# Simulation loop GPU utilization

Tags: cuda, utilization

I am struggling with utilizing a simulation loop.
There are 3 kernel launched in every cycle.
The next time step size is computed by the second kernel.

```
while (time < end)
{
  kernel_Flux<<<>>>(...);
  kernel_Timestep<<<>>>(d_timestep);
  memcpy(&h_timestep, d_timestep, sizeof(float), ...);  
  kernel_Integrate<<<>>>(d_timestep);
  time += h_timestep;
}
```

I only need copy back a single float. What would be the most efficient way to avoid unnecessary synchronizations?

Thank you in advance. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal solution would be to move everything to the GPU. However, I cannot do so, because I need to launch CUDPP compact after every few iterations, and it does not support CUDA streams nor dynamics parallelism. I know that the Thrust 1.8 library has copy_if method, which does the same, and it is working with dynamic parallelism. The problem is it does not compile with separate compilation on.

To sum up, now I use the following code:

```
while (time < end)
{
  kernel_Flux<<<gs,bs, 0, stream1>>>();
  kernel_Timestep<<<gs,bs, 0, stream1>>>(d_timestep);
  cudaEventRecord(event, stream1);
  cudaStreamWaitEvent(mStream2, event, 0);
  memcpyasync(&h_timestep, d_timestep, sizeof(float), ..., stream2);  
  kernel_Integrate<<<>>>(d_timestep);
  cudaStreamSynchronize(stream2);
  time += h_timestep;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In CUDA all operations running from the default stream are synchronized. So in the code you've posted kernels will run one after another. From what I can see the kernel ***kernel_integrate()*** depends from the result of the kernel ***kernel_Timestep()***, so no way of avoiding synchronization. Anyway if the kernels ***kernel_Flux()*** and ***kernel_Timestep()*** work on independent data, you can try to execute them in parallel, in two different streams.

Comment: My problem is not that the kernels are running one after the other, but the memcpy. It delays the whole process.

Comment: I am currently using nonblocking streams, one for the kernels and one for the memory transfer, and the h_timestep is allocated with cudaMallocHost.

Comment: @hrvthzs do you think it might have been important to add those details in your question?

Comment: @talonmies When I posted my question it was without streams.

Answer (score 1):

If you care about the iteration time a lot, you can probably setup a new stream dedicated to the memcpy of the h_timestep out (you need to use cudaMemcpyAsync in this case). Then use something like speculative execution, where your loop proceeds before you figure out the time. To do so you will have to setup the GPU memory buffers for the next several iterations. You can probably do this by using a circular buffer. You also need to use `cudaEventRecord` and `cudaStreamWaitEvent` to synchronize the different streams, such that a next iteration is allowed to proceed only if the time corresponds to the buffer you are about to overwrite, has been calculated (the memcpy stream has done the job), because otherwise you will lose the state at that iteration.

Another potential solution, which I haven't tried but I suspect would work, is to make use of dynamic parallelism. If your cards support that, you can probably put the whole loop in GPU.

EDIT:

Sorry, I just realized that you have the third kernel. Your delay due to synchronization may be because you are not doing `cudaMemcpyAsync`? It's very likely that the third kernel will run longer than the memcpy. You should be able to proceed without any delay. The only synchronization needed is after each iteration.